# How do I integrate chat with nodejs and xmpp into my existing web application?

Tags: node.js, redis, xmpp, mqtt

I have read a lot of questions relating this, but none of them are satisfying.

***Existing App***

> A minimalist social network implemented using **Expressjs** as an
>   API.Using **MySql** as DB.**socket.io** for notifications and
>   **ember.js** as a frontend framework.

***What I want to integrate***

I want to implements only a few features of XMPP such as

> - Peer 2 Peer Messaging
> - Presence and Last Seen
> - Group Chat
> - Read Receipts

***A basic idea I got from reading similar questions.***

> 1. Need a client library (Strophe.js,Converse.js)
> 2. Need a XMPP server (ejabberd,Openfire,Prosody)

***Questions***

1. How do I integrate chat here ?
2. How do I authenticate XMPP users (FYI, I have JWT Authentication implemented currently) ?
3. Suggestions on using redis(pub/sub) with socket.io or mqtt pub/sub for implementing the chat.Is it scalable ? / What about performance ?

> What I asked might be too broad.But still don't have any idea on using which set technologies to use.

Comment: This question is way too broad, but since you've added a bounty I can't vote to have it closed. What your basically looking for here will require paying for a consultant to do it for you

Comment: @hardillb: not running a company to afford consulting.Just asking for learning purposes.Can't learn all this in one shot.Takes time.So just asking the best way to do this.

Comment: @vishwasraj : Did you find any solution? What client side library/framework did you use finally?

Answer (score 1):

For learning purpose you can achieve all things using ejabberd+converse.js
Below steps will setup environment in ubuntu

1. setup ejabberd by following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu
2. create a host binding by editing **/etc/hosts** file in ubuntu

   ```
   127.0.1.2       talk.rajesh6115.local
   ```
3. install apache2 using

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install apache2
   ```
4. setup a virtual host for  bosh (XEP-0206) in your apache like below
   /etc/apache2/sites-available/talk.rajesh6115.local.conf

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName talk.rajesh6115.local
       ServerAlias www.talk.rajesh6115.local
       ServerAdmin webmaster@talk.rajesh6115.local
       DocumentRoot /var/www/talk.rajesh6115.local
       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
       ProxyPass /http-bind http://talk.rajesh6115.local:5280/http-bind/
       ProxyPassReverse /http-bind http://talk.rajesh6115.local:5280/http-bind/
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. now you can configure converse js to point to your bosh service, then your communications starts

NOTE:

setup a virtual host in ejabberd by adding a line like below

```
    hosts:
      - "talk.rajesh6115.local"
```

setup a admin login. using this login you can create user.

```
  admin:
     user:
         - "admin": "talk.rajesh6115.local"
```

6. for make conversejs talk with xmpp server only one thing you have to give that is bosh serivce url. for more details
   https://conversejs.org/docs/html/development.html#initialize

7.finally how to integrate with web application?

**Method1 (simple):**
use same logins for webapp and xmpp means rajesh@talk.rajesh6115.local can be a email address also a valid jid

**Method2:**
Use a authentication server which will return both jid and password after successful authentication, then start your xmpp session using provided credential.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use socket.io, since you are currently using JWT authentication and it can be implementing authentication using NodeJS. You can create so call room in socket.io for peer to peer to messaging or goroup chat. I read your comment and since it's for learning purposes Mysql is scalable enough. For the sake of performance using a load balancer like nginx or even can use NodeJS load balancer with horizontally scaling technique can extend performance easily. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Given your original idea how to solve this, I'd suggest that you take a look at [node-xmpp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xmpp-client) and [node-xmpp-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xmpp-server).

It's an excellent set of libraries and you can use them to fully integrate your application on a nodejs level. So you'd be able to control authentication yourself (use existing users/pws in your app?), and be notified when a message in a (group) chat appears.

Of course you can use an existing server like prosody or ejabberd, as a backend for chats. In my experience it's not much work to get node-xmpp-client integrated. But building/running an XMPP-server with nodejs (that can actually talk to other servers) is not that trivial - a little more that the examples thrown together yield, unfortunately.

Also, XMPP being text-based, actually even worse, xml-based... it's not really the definition of efficient. Let alone the complexity of all the modules supporting node-xmpp :)

**So**

If you are worried about performance and don't need XMPP per-se and really only want the features above, XMPP is a **bad** choice. It's far to wasteful for your original purposes.

So something like [zmq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zmq) should enable you to implement group and personal chats.

redis could be used to save chat histories, presence information and message reciepts.

To my knowledge there is no library for node that would just give you what you want for free, and IMHO the way using XMPP is even harder than implementing your features with tools like zmq and a datastore as backing on your own.